# Is ETag returned in a 304 response?

Tags: http, http-status-codes, http-status-code-304

I'm building a node.js app which - reguarly, once a day - fetches data from some external web server (using "[request](https://github.com/request/request)" package).

I want to avoid fetching same data twice, so I keep track of each resource ETag when first downloading (`200` status code).

Then, when fetching again (next day) that resource I add an `If-None-Match` header with the saved etag in the request.

Since I suspect to sometime receive a `200` status code (instead of expected `304`) from the remote web server even if a resource contents is not modified, I ask if I should expect the resource `ETag` to be returned in a `304` response (and how to get it in the `request` response...), to try to debug this issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please have a look at appropriate [RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt).

> The response MUST include the following header fields: (...)
>
> - ETag and/or Content-Location, if the header would have been sent
>   in a 200 response to the same request

So if `ETag` header is returned with `200 OK` status code it also must be included in `304 Not Modified` response.

Comment: What about the newer RFCs? Is it mentioned in them at all?

Comment: Found it in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232#section-4.1

`The server generating a 304 response MUST generate any of the
   following header fields that would have been sent in a 200 (OK)
   response to the same request: Cache-Control, Content-Location, Date,
   ETag, Expires, and Vary.`